# How to cast generic collections in F#

Tags: f#, upcasting

Given

```
type X () = class  end    

type XX () =  inherit X() 

type NestedList<'T> = list<list<'T>>

let xxs  = [[ XX() ]] // list<list<XX>>
```

What is the best way to cast from `list<list<XX>>` to  `NestedList<X>` ?

This fails:

```
let xs = xxs :> NestedList<X> //fails
```

This works but reallocates the list. Is there a more elegant way doing this without reallocation?

```
let xs : NestedList<X> = [ for xx in xxs do yield List.ofSeq (Seq.cast<X> xx) ]
```

How could I define a `cast` function on `NestedList<'T>` ? (like `Seq.cast`)

Comment: `let xxs: NestedList<_> = [ [ XX() :> X ] ]` I guess.

Comment: @SerejaBogolubov yes that would work, but what if `xss` is given too. I edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`let cast xxs = xxs |> List.map (List.map (fun e -> e :> X))` would do the job.

More fancy way:

```
let mapNested f = (List.map >> List.map) f
let cast xxs = mapNested (fun e -> e :> X) xxs
```

P.S. I strongly recommend avoid unnecessary abstractions like `NestedList<'T>` from your example.